# Agora.io Unreal Engine Plugin Build error

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, agora.io

when i try to rebuild the sample or the plugin, i have some errors in the visual studio console

1-
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Library 'agora_rtc_sdk.lib' was not resolvable to a file when used in Module 'Agora', assuming it is a filename and will search library paths for it. This is slow and dependency checking will not work for it. Please update reference to be fully qualified alternatively use PublicSystemLibraryPaths if you do intended to use this slow path to suppress this warning.    AgoraVideoCall  C:\Users\Ahmed Hassn\Desktop\Agora-Unreal-SDK-Blueprint-master\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\UnrealBuildTool    1

2-

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Expected an include at the top of the header: '#include "GameplayTagsK2Node_MultiCompareGameplayTagAssetInterfaceSingle.generated.h"'   AgoraVideoCall  C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Plugins\Editor\GameplayTagsEditor\Source\GameplayTagsEditor\Classes\GameplayTagsK2Node_MultiCompareGameplayTagAssetInterfaceSingle.h 32

3-

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Rebuild.bat" AgoraVideoCallEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\Ahmed Hassn\Desktop\Agora-Unreal-SDK-Blueprint-master\AgoraVideoCall.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code -1.   AgoraVideoCall  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets  49

those the three errors i got when i try to build in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

in context to building the project, which of these build descriptions fit your situation?
Is this during:

- the initial project opening ie: "build agora modules?"
- packaging/building the project to test a standalone build.

Thanks!